# Laravel Validation Check if password exists

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to check if a password is correct of a particular user in the database. I want to use Laravel validation for this purpose

.
Here is my current code

```
$validator = $request->validate([
        'password' => ['required',Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) { $query->where('id',Auth::id()); })]
    ]);
```

I think this generates the query

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `password` = 123 and id = 1))
```

What's missing is that I want this password (123) to be hashed to get checked properly.
Currently, I get the validation error

> The selected password is invalid

Even I am entering the correct password

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing `Hash::check()`

Comment: Why don't you create a custom validation rule? See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: If you want to check hashed password then do like: `$user = \App\Models\User::findOrFail($user_id); $check_password = Hash::check($request->password, $user->password);`

Comment: @HirenGohel Read the OP: "I want to use Laravel validation for this purpose."

Comment: @Jeffrey I know that, but OP can also check like this password in DB.

Comment: @HirenGohel But that doesn't answer his question, so what's the point?

Comment: @Jeffrey I give suggestion only! Had i post my answer! No! I just give a comment only!

Comment: Or you can add the hashed password to the request like this `$request->request->add(['hashed_password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))]);` then validate the hashed password if it exists ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you should create your own `Validation Rule` following [this instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules)

```
php artisan make:rule ValidatePassword
```

In the generated file, add the constructor method for receive the user you want to validate password against

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

You should write the logic for checking the password inside the `passes` method

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Hash::check($value, $this->user->password);
}
```

Then, you can use it like

```
$validator = $request->validate([
    'password' => ['required', new ValidatePassword(auth()->user())]
]);
```

Make sure to import `User`, `ValidatePassword` and `Hash`, I skipped that for brevity.

Comment: I'd recommend passing the `User` object through the constructor of your `ValidatePassword` class. It seems like a universal rule and you made the assumption it's always used on the currently authenticated user.

Comment: auth()->user()->password How will I get the hashed password from database here.

Comment: @YasirIjaz `auth()->user()`  gets the current logged in user. But as suggested by @Jeffrey, better to pass the user as a parameter. I'll edit the answer for that